# Is there a way to instantiate C++ template as C code?

Tags: c++, opencl, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler

I am targeting *OpenCL* and forced to write code in *C*, so am really missing *C++ templates*. Currently doing string substitution on *C* sources when sending code to *OpenCL* compiler which is error-prone.
In general, my question is **how to generate C code from C++?**, but out of *C++* I mostly need just template instantiation feature. Polymorphism isn't needed, though inheritance and **auto** would be nice, but not as important as templates, which begs being easy to steal from **g++** functionality or something.

Comment: Why do you need C code? If it's because your existing codebase is C, but you still have a C++ compiler on hand, a better approach would be to create a C binding that wraps the C++ code with standalone functions and liberal use of `extern "C"`. Then you could compile the C++ code with a C++ compiler and still call it and link to it from plain C code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thank you for your comment! I need C code to target **OpenCL** device - it requires **C code**. There is SYCL tech stack (and some others less prominent) which allows target OpenCL with C++, but it already (around ~2 years ago) died out and not supported by most of the drivers.

Comment: You might be able to rewrite that template code as `#define` code. This was actually how very early container libraries worked.

Comment: @JosephLarson if I understand properly, it's equivalent to naive substring substitution which I am currently doing, but it doesn't work with nested templates, for example; and I have to make sure it targets **only** templates, so name them ~ **_TEMPLATE_FOO_**, etc.

Comment: @Slaus I wouldn't want to do it with a significant amount of C++ code, that's for sure. Not fun.

Comment: @JosephLarson writing **C** after 10 years of **C++** is even less fun 

Comment: When you get a chance, review the `try/catch/throw` mechanism and find a good way to implement in C.  I've only seen a few valid implementations in all my experience.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews **OpenCL** doesn't have `try/catch/throw` and I don't need either (it doesn't even have `malloc` nor `printf`). I need to *just* instantiate (unroll) templates due to types complexity.

Comment: Exactly like you generate assembly code from C++ — with a compiler that outputs C as its object code. (You probably need to write one, because this breed has died out, but if you can dig out Comeau C++, try it).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There are `try/catch/throw` implementations for C, too. The 16-bit Windows API (Windows 3.x) came with such an implementation. However, these implementations are not written in C but in assembly.

Comment: Early C++ compilers compiled C++ to C, not to assembler. You could try to get such an old compiler. However, *templates* were a feature that was added to C++ much later. Those old compilers would not support templates.

Comment: Perhaps you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#C++_for_OpenCL_language instead.

Comment: On [the ISO C++ website](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/compiler-dependencies#convert-to-c), there is a list of more modern C++ compilers that generate C code.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/JuliaComputingOSS/llvm-cbe It is a reintroduction of a C backend for LLVM 10/11 (we are talking about up to C++20 :-) ). The included Unit Test compiles a .cpp file into C.

Comment: @Slaus your statement "There is SYCL tech stack (and some others less prominent) which allows target OpenCL with C++, but it already (around ~2 years ago) died out and not supported by most of the driver" is not correct. There are numerous SYCL implementations available (DPC++, hipSYCL, ComputeCpp) that are very much under development still. You may be referring to the OpenCL C++ implementation which is less supported. SYCL is being used on the Aurora exascale supercomputer amongst others so is very much here to stay.

Comment: @RodBurns Thanks for info, especially interesting [SYCL ecosystem](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/raw/develop/doc/img/sycl-targets.png). My **Radeon RX 5700** doesn't support SYCL: turned out AMD didn't supported SPIR-V (ROCm) drivers for it's most popular series of GPUs for last ~3 years, but SYCL requires SPIR-V, though AMD was the most prominent SPIR-V supporter in Khronos group. But it supports OpenCL (which is C). Some devices might work out of C++ code, but C will work on everything past 50 years? Even FPGAs. I don't have $500M device in my disposal nor PhD coder instead of myself.

Comment: @Slaus hipSYCL and the experimental support in DPC++ for HIP (https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#build-dpc-toolchain-with-support-for-hip-amd) don't require SPIR-V or OpenCL so should work. But I agree that it is a frustration that AMD drivers don't support SPIR fully.